# "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument - docker build error

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    ca-certificates \
    gcc \
    git \
    libpq-dev \
    make \
    python-pip \
    python2.7 \
    python2.7-dev \
    ssh \
    && apt-get autoremove \
    && apt-get clean

ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
RUN echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan http://bitbuckrt.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts    

RUN pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/repo.git
```

I am building the Docker image from this Dockerfile using the following command:

```
docker build -t myimage:v1 --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="ssh-rsa jkdfjgklfsgnkljgxdfeheflkfkl/hkskkdhgtgshshsh/... " .
```

However, it is not building my image. I get the following error:

```
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
```

What could be the issue? How to correctly pass the `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` while building the image?

Comment: Everything is correct, check the value of the key for characters which may break the command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign your private key to a bash variable and use it in the command. Reading the key from a file while assigning to the variable is the safest. The special chars inside the key might be screwing the command if it has, say, a quotation mark. Ex:

```
PKEY=$(<key.txt)
docker build -t myimage:v1 --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=$PKEY .
```